# Declaring an Iterator before adding elements to a Collection

Tags: java, iterator, fail-fast

If you create your own `Iterable` container class and retrieve a `java.util.Iterator` over its elements, is there any coding pattern according to which any further additions of elements in the container should **not** be accessible from the `Iterator`? I'm thinking "no way, absolutely not, in fact the `Iterator` should be able to loop through all of the elements regardless of additions."

Or is it perhaps the case that a fail-fast `Iterator` should throw an Exception if `next()` is called after a new addition is made?

Been a while since I've coded in Java yet something stinks here.

Comment: The second is true. I believe if you try and do that with any of Java's inbuilt `Iterable`s you'll get a [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: You are most definitely correct in that, I looked up some of my older code and this is exactly what I ought to do. I wish you had answered this formally so I could accept it as an answer. This I now consider solved.

Comment: Done! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it perhaps the case that a fail-fast Iterator should throw an
>   Exception if `next()` is called after a new addition is made?

Correct. I believe if you try and do that with any of Java's inbuilt [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)s you'll get a [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

The entire [Javadoc for that exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is worth a read regarding this. It's very concise. Rather than quote the whole thing, the salient point is that iterators which do not fail fast "*[risk] arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.*"

Answer (score 0):

User Michael answered my question in the comment above. Fail-fast Iterators should do exactly the latter. Now when one should prefer Fail-fast over Fail-safe, I'm not sure, but given that containers are mutable by definition, I believe Fail-Fast might be the only way to go.

Comment: Fail-safe iterators have their usages but fail-fast is often preferable. Fail-safe iterators are okay provided copying the collection is not a problem (which it may be for large datasets) and you don't care whether the data you have is the most recent.